# Laravel-Bouncer: Get all Users with ability to a specific model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to check for all users on a Contract model with a specific ID.

[In this issue](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/126#issuecomment-246983616) there is a solution, when you only need the ability name.
How could I add a check for the Model?

I want to use it like:

$users = User::whereCan('contract-show', $contract);

and get all users with 'contract-show' in general and 'contract-show' on this specific model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with filtering:

```
$users = User::all();

$filtered = $users->filter(function ($user) use ($entity) 
{
      return  $user->can('contract-show', $entity);
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that it will trigger queries per user. It's not very performant.